# Sampling for a SQL Database

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a column "steak" representing the amount of steak in pounds my firm has bought since day 1 of 2010. 
I have another column "c_steak" representing the cumulative sum of pounds of steak.

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ steak      ║ c_steak     ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 0.2        ║ 0.2         ║
║ 2 ║ 0.2        ║ 0.4         ║
║ 3 ║ 0.3        ║ 0.7         ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

How do I sample the table such that a row is taken once we buy another 100 pounds of steak? (sample ONE row immediately after c_steak reaches 100, 200, 300, 400 etc).

Note(EDIT):

1. c_steak is float. It may not exactly hit 100, 200, 300....
2. If c_steak goes like ..., 99.5, 105.3, 107.1, ... then the row corresponding to 105.3 will be sampled.
3. if c_steak goes like ..., 99, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3, 105..., then the row corresponding to 100.1 will be sampled.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you show sample data and expected output? Also, tag your question with which SQL DBMS you're using (ex: sql-server, mysql, oracle, etc.)

Comment: @dvo sure will do.

Comment: all done! @dvo.

Comment: @user1559897 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your reputation should know how to tag a question.  Please explain what *you* mean by "sample the table".  The question is unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Edited!  should be clearer now.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I don't want to waste time writing an answer for "wrong" database.)

Comment: @jarlh i am using vertica, but you can write in standard SQL and i will do the translation.

Comment: ANSI SQL: `select * from tablename where c_steak >= 100 order by c_steak fetch first 1 row only`

Answer (score 2):

It almost certain you need `LAG` method. You can try like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT c_steak
        ,lag(c_steak, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) lg
     FROM myTable
    ) sub
WHERE cast(sub.c_steak as int) %100 - cast(sub.lg as int)% 100 < 0
```

The logic is that when you reach a sum of 100, 200 etc, the difference in modulus with the previous value should be negative.
e.g:

```
80%100 = 80 where as 101%100 = 1
195%100 = 95 where as 205%100 = 5
293%100 = 93 where as 320%100 = 20
etc
```

Comment: i like your idea. checking the integer quotient of a/b probably works better. When the integer quotient c_steak/100 differs from the previous row, take a sample.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
   SELECT m2.id,m2.steak,m2.c_steak FROM t1 as m1 inner join t1 as m2 on m2.id = m1.id + 1 WHERE cast(m2.c_steak as int) % 100 < cast(m1.c_steak as int) % 100;
```

Look here:

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b96fb569ab3033b40f498fcb1b31514)

===========

EDIT (in case id column skips at all):

```
   SELECT distinct m2.id,m2.steak,m2.c_steak FROM t1 as m1 inner join t1 as m2 on m2.id > m1.id WHERE cast(m2.c_steak as int) % 100 < cast(m1.c_steak as int) % 100;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3e080d658bb1d2577639a2e8fdf4226)

===========

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOD() function. Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE MOD(c_steak, 100) = 0;
```

EDIT:
In response to OPs edit, you can use FLOOR() on c_steak to get an int. Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE MOD(FLOOR(c_steak), 100) = 0;
```

Comment: what if c_steak has multiple rows w/ floor(c_steak) = 100? i.e. 99, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3, 100.4, 101.2 ...

Comment: Well, the query won't work in that case. What exactly are you trying to select? The row when c_steak reaches 105.3 in this case?

Comment: For the first example, YES. I am trying to sample ONE row every time c_steak reaches 100, 200, 300, 400 etc...

Comment: Right....but as you pointed out, c_steak may not reach 100, 200, etc exactly. So the question is what would you want in that case?

Comment: This is a complicated problem. Sounds like you need a function that will check every row and compare the previous row to the current row to see if it passed a factor of 100.

Comment: as i said, i want the first row once it reaches 100, 200, 300...

Answer (score 0):

You could have supplied some sample data.

Doing it now :

```
WITH    
-- sample data , this will be in the table                                                                    
input(id,steak_sold) AS (
          SELECT  1,30.07  
UNION ALL SELECT  2,30.01 
UNION ALL SELECT  3,30.02 
UNION ALL SELECT  4,30.03 
UNION ALL SELECT  5,30.04 
UNION ALL SELECT  6,30.05 
UNION ALL SELECT  7,30.06 
UNION ALL SELECT  8,30.07 
UNION ALL SELECT  9,30.08 
UNION ALL SELECT 10,30.09 
UNION ALL SELECT 11,30.10
UNION ALL SELECT 12,30.11
UNION ALL SELECT 13,30.12
UNION ALL SELECT 14,30.13
UNION ALL SELECT 15,30.14
UNION ALL SELECT 16,30.15
UNION ALL SELECT 17,30.16
)
-- real WITH clause would begin here: creating running sum myself ....
,
runsum AS (
SELECT
  *
, SUM(steak_sold) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS c_steak
FROM input
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM runsum
-- this running sum is above a certain 100 
-- previous (running sum - steak_sold) below that 100
-- integer division by 100 of the two differs
WHERE c_steak//100 <> (c_steak - steak_sold) //100;
-- out  id | steak_sold | c_steak 
-- out ----+------------+---------
-- out   4 |      30.03 |  120.13
-- out   7 |      30.06 |  210.28
-- out  10 |      30.09 |  300.52
-- out  14 |      30.13 |  420.98
-- out  17 |      30.16 |  511.43
-- out (5 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (5 rows): 53.018 ms. All rows formatted: 53.066 ms
```